# How can I display all users and groups with a command?

Tags: command-line, users, groups

I want to display:

1. All users and
2. All groups

   in my system using command-line.

`users` and `groups` commands display users currently logged in, and groups a user belongs to respectively.

How to display a list of all users and all groups by command-line?

Answer (score 289, accepted):

You can display with the help of **`compgen`** builtin command as follows:

1. To display all users run following command:

   ```
   compgen -u
   ```
2. To display all groups run following command:

   ```
   compgen -g
   ```

However you can also display all users by `cut -d ":" -f 1 /etc/passwd`.

Comment: Nice! it might be preferable to use `getent passwd` / `getent group` instead of cat'ing the local files (`getent` should work for non-local accounts as well)

Comment: @steeldriver `compgen` does seem to work for non-local accounts (at least for LDAP).

Comment: @muru I was referring to the second method specifically (`cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ...`)

Comment: @steeldriver Ah, sorry. I thought that was a more general observation.

Comment: Well, on my ubuntu, I have some files created by docker mount with `999:999` as `user:group`, but unfortunately none of the above commands prints them.

Answer (score 26):

Here we are going to use `getent` for the detailed the info

We can list the user with the following command:

```
getent passwd
```

We can list the group as follows:

```
getent group
```

To fetch detail a specific user

```
getent passwd lalit
```

Replace the lalit with your user name. Lalit will not be in every system :)

You can read the more into about `getent` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getent-command-in-linux-with-examples/)